# EntityFramework performance

Tags: query-performance

Why is EF (6) so slow for a very simple query of a few rows?
My test db has only one table and I read all rows (say 80) and by EF I need about 2500 ms (SQL Express on local machine) while SqlDataReader using the exact same sql query only needs about 150 ms.

Increasing the number of rows doesn't make EF much slower so it seems like this is a one timer overhead (and running the same query again is blizzard fast).

Is there some setting which may be used to persist some compilation or sql execution strategy or something like that?

Comment: Do you have Eager Loading turned on?

Comment: No and it doesn't matter I think, my model (just for some simple test) contains one single table and read all the rows by: int myRowsCount = myContext.MyTable.Count();

Comment: So you don't have any foreign keys? Can you post the class in your question?

Comment: No foreign keys, but I think I know the reason (and it expose my lack of even basic knowledge of EF internals), I think I am hit by the "Cold Query syndrom" (View generation mostly): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/performance-considerations.
Havent tried yet to offload this to the compiler, but will do.